# NullReferenceException with Entity Framework and Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I'm saving data using the Entity Framework in a Parallel.ForEach loop.
Knowing that the EF is not thread-safe, I instanciate an entity context for each of my thread.

1- Is it safe?
It seems to be as I see in these posts:

[Entity Framework + Multiple Threads + Lazy Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176303/entity-framework-multiple-threads-lazy-load)

[Is it safe to use one Entity Framework Context per thread? ... yes? how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491869/is-it-safe-to-use-one-entity-framework-context-per-thread-yes-how)

2-There is an exception during the creation of my context, but only one time out of 3 and I can't found out why.

Here is my code creating the context:

```
public partial class Entities
{
    private static Entities mfgEntities = new Entities();
    private static readonly Dictionary<int,Entities>  ThreadContexts = new Dictionary<int, Entities>();

    public static Entities Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                string objectContextKey = HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(objectContextKey))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(objectContextKey, new Entities());
                }
                return HttpContext.Current.Items[objectContextKey] as Entities;
            }
            else
            {
                int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                if (!ThreadContexts.ContainsKey(threadId))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ThreadContexts.Add(threadId, new Entities());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Erreur lors de la création de l'entity context");
                    }
                }
                return ThreadContexts[threadId];
            }
            return mfgEntities;
        }
    }
}
```

It throws a NullReferenceException on line :

```
ThreadContexts.Add(threadId, new Entities());
```

And ThreadContexts, threadId and the new Entities are not null.

I thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the database behind it? Is it Oracle?

Comment: It's impossible for a NullRef exception to be thrown on that line.  Are you compiling with debug symbols?  Are you sure that when you break you're on the right thread's call stack?

Comment: This is a SQLServer database.

Comment: @Slugart I'm compiling in debug mode and I'm quite sure I break on the right thread's call.
I'm also confused with this NullReferenceException on that line but that's what's happening.

Comment: @Leslie I would try making things more explicit to expose the impossibility of the exception.  Break out new Entities() into a var and then assert not null on each of the three vars before calling Add().  Also try cleaning and rebuilding everything.

Comment: @Slugart I already tried cleaning and rebuilding, and it still throws the exception in a random way.

Changing my code by:
     Entities ent = new Entities();
                            if (ThreadContexts != null && threadId!= null && ent != null)
                                ThreadContexts.Add(threadId, ent);

It enters the if statement and then still throws the exception.

Comment: You should use a [thread-safe dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: The ConcurrentDictionary seems to work great. Thank you GertArnold!
And thanks to all for you help.

Is there a way to put the post as resolved?

Comment: I put it into an answer, with another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) for `ThreadContexts`.

Better even: find a way to capture a context instance in a thread, e.g. by executing [parallel tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx):

```
var task1 = new Task(() => <your method that instantiates a context>));
```